# How to measure variance of a population of permutations?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, variance, traveling-salesman

I need to compute the variance in a population (*array*) of permutations, i.e,

Let say that I have this array of permutations:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats


a = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,6,1,5], [6,3,1,2,5,4]])

# distance between a[0] and a[1]
distance = stats.kendalltau(a[0], a[1])[0]
```

So, how to compute (in Python) the variance on this array, i.e, how to measure how far theses permutations are from each other ?

Regards

Aymeric

p.s: I define the distance between two permutation by the kendalltau metric

Comment: Can you give some example of what you mean by "how far theses permutations are from each other"?

Comment: How would you define mathematically the variance between `[1,3,4]` and `[2,5,6]` for example?

Comment: @loaTzimas Hello, I just updated my code

Comment: Thanks for the update. So you want to calculate the distance for all possible pairs inside the list?

Comment: Hi @ailauli69, could you clarify what you want to compute the distance between? its not really clear? could you give an example ?

Comment: Hello, I mentioned how I compute the distance between 2 elements, because I thought it is useful for computing the variance. I need to compute the variance of the general population

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the mathematical result you are looking for. You could use `stats.kendalltau` to compute the distance for all possible pairs, then take the variance from that resulting vector.

To get the vector of distances, I loop through the zipped list `(a, a-shifted)` using [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
dist = []
for x1, x2 in zip(a, np.roll(a, shift=1, axis=0)):
    dist.append(kendalltau(x1, x2)[0])
```

To take the variance of all distances:

```
np.std(dist)
```

Or if you are looking for the variance as [image] ([discussed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20108/link-between-variance-and-pairwise-distances-within-a-variable))
then take the norm of the distance vector:

```
np.linalg.norm(dist)
```

---

Note I'm using `a` as defined with `np.array`, not `np.matrix`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,6,1,5], [6,3,1,2,5,4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for something that broadcasts the `kendalltau` function over each of the 3 arrays and permutes over them. The output in that case will be a `3x3` matrix. I am not sure of what you are looking for when you say you want the variance, however. Do clarify in the comments and I'll update my answer accordingly. Hope this helps -

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,6,1,5], [6,3,1,2,5,4]])

def f(a,b):
    return np.array(stats.kendalltau(a,b)[0])

vf = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(m)->()')

out = vf(a[:,None,:],a[None,:,:])
print(out)
```

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.33333333, -0.06666667],
       [ 0.33333333,  1.        , -0.46666667],
       [-0.06666667, -0.46666667,  1.        ]])
```

---

> So, how to compute (in Python) the variance on this array, i.e, how to measure how far theses permutations are from each other ?

IIUC, if you are trying to calculate the `kendalltau` distances between each of the combinations and then check the standard deviation between the distances, you can filter our the lower triangular matrix (without diagonal) using `np.tril_indices(k=-1)` and then fetch the 3 values to take a `np.std`

```
np.std(out[np.tril_indices(out.shape[0], k=-1)])
```

```
0.3265986323710904
```